# How to setup up the folder structure of angular 2 app?

Tags: php, html, typescript, angular

I have been following the Angular 2 Tour of Heroes tutorial and Quick Start guide on anuglar.io. In the tutorials all the of the files are directly under the app folder. I have started my own project and I want to set up the folder structure where I Have a components folder, services folder, and directives folder all under the app folder for the project. Under each of these folders I would also like to have folders the house each individual component to include the ts, js, map, and the html files relating to the component so for instance. It would look something like this:

```
-My_Project
  - app
     - components
        -app
          - app.component.ts
          - app.component.js
          - app.component.map
          - app.component.html
        -logon
          - logon.component.ts
          - logon.component.js
          - logon.component.map
          - logon.component.html
      - services
         -user
          - user.services.ts
          - user.services.js
          - user.services.map
```

so on and so forth.

I understand about using absolute and relative paths and using `../` to move up to the parent folder and `../../` to go back two folders in the path, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working with the lite server. This works just fine when i run the app with Windows IIS 7.5. When I try to run the compiler I get errors of the following nature:

`app - Copy/app.component.ts(6,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module './logon/logon.component'.`

I am using the following to reference the logon.component file from the app.component file.

```js
 import { LogonComponent } from '../logon/logon.component';
```

Also I have some PHP files in a php folder located in the Project folder. This again works fine when ran on Windows IIS 7.5 but when i try and run it with the lite server I get a 404 error when these php files are needed.

**Edit**

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

Here is my pacakage.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
```

Comment: To answer the question in the title: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html Regarding not being able to load the files: what is "the lite server"?

Comment: Can you share your tsconfig.json and the relevant lines of your package.json (npm scripts you're using)?

Comment: lite server is a the devDependency that is used in the tutorials for development. lite-server 2.2.0.

Comment: The error message you provided also doesn't seem to match the folder structure (What is Copy/? Why can't tsc find './logon/logon.component'? (should be '../logon/logon.component' given your import statement))

Comment: That is the odd part if i break the `import { LogonComponent } from '../logon/logon.component';`  so that is points somewhere else I get this error: `app/components/app..components.ts(6,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '.logon/logon.component'.`.I am not sure where the copy error is coming from. I have for all the other components referenced from the app.component file.